# "Thank you all" — wrong or right?

Tags: grammaticality, politeness, progressive-aspect

On many occasions after we complete a speech, we often consider thanking our audience. In this scenario, I am not sure if "Thank you all" is the right English. Should it be "Thanking you all" instead to make it sound correct?

Comment: Would it be okay to just say "I thank all of you"?

Comment: Well this is perfect, but I am curious if above mentioned statement is correct, as subconsciously I tend to use "Thank you all", and I did that recently so..

Comment: I was actually wondering about _thanks very much_ which I have often heard from British people. _Many thanks_ looks far more grammatically correct than _thanks very much_ because _much_ does not go with countable nouns.

Answer (score 11):

"(I) thank you all" is correct English, and a complete sentence.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. Can you also quote some resource(related link), need to forward it.

Comment: [We Are the Champions](http://www.queenwords.com/lyrics/songs/sng11_17.shtml), line 22, Freddy Mercury, 1977.

Answer (score 5):

"Thank you all" is correct because the "I" is implied. The verb "to thank" is correctly conjugated as "thank" for the subject "I." Correct as is!

The word "you", in English, can be singular or plural. This is different than in some other languages such as French where there is a distinction between "tu" and "vous" that can either be the formality of the situation or if the addressed are plural or singular.

So "you all" is correct just as much as using "you" to refer to a single person. As one commenter said it is compulsory in southern US dialects where they commonly run the two words together as in "y'all."

Comment: But can **you** and **all** go together?

Comment: @samridhi: In the Southern USA, it's practically compulsory ;)  But seriously, *you* can be singular or plural; *all of you* is a common phrase; where do you see a problem?

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks for clarifying, I was just digging logically so got a bit confused. I have been using this phrase since long, but suddenly, a thought baffled me.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you *not* residing in the southern or southwestern US, "(I) thank y'all." is also correct English, and a complete sentence.

Answer (score -1):

*Thank you all* sounds ok colloquially, but in correct written English a noun or pronoun must always be present, not merely implied.

*I thank you all* or *I thank all of you* would be my first picks.

Comment: Under what authority must the subject in correct written English always be present and not merly implied? Implied "You" is used very frequently and I've never had any reason to consider it incorrect.

Comment: And a Happy New Year.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about the phrase "thank you." It is an idiom. Someone who forces themselves to always write "I thank you" would sound overly stilted in the same way as if they never used contractions like "didn't" or "won't".

Comment: The British comedian Arthur Askey  used 'I thank you!' as a catchphrase, I believe - though it sounded more like 'Aathaangeoo!' _Overly stilted_ is right.